# Predicting values from csv file in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've created a linear classification model and stored a checkpoint for it on my hard drive.

In a different python file, I'm looking to restore the model, and predict values using the model for data that's stored in a CSV file. I've got the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

# file with data that must be predicted
file = 'census_predict.csv'
x_test = pd.read_csv(file)

print(x_test)

# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3])
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5])

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
# do some work with the model.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver.restore(sess, "models/1/1.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")


    pred_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=x_test, batch_size=len(x_test), shuffle=False)
    predictions = list(sess.predict(input_fn=pred_fn))
    print(predictions)

# close TF session in case a new one must be created later on
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess.close()
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I've been looking all over stackoverflow and other websites, but can't seem to figure out how to get it right. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: not sure but the error means that there isn't a predict method on your session object. The docs should say where the method is or if it's spelt differently.

Comment: It's because there isn't a predict method on the session object I think. But I don't know on where to use the predict method.